# How to sort based on number of specific characters in vim?

Tags: sorting, vim

I have a file where certain lines are *tagged* with multiple pipes for relative importance.
How would you sort these lines in vim based on importance and also alphabetically?

**Input**

```
cli
bar ||
bar
foo |||
haz ||
```

**Output**

```
foo |||
bar ||
haz ||
bar
cli
```

Note that *bar* and *haz* are sorted by number of pipes but also alphabetically.
Thanks!

Comment: Was `bar` meant to come before `cli` as well? or only if also sorted by pipes?

Comment: Yes! I'm sorry. I got the output wrong. 
Indeed *bar* should go before *cli*.

Comment: Edited to proper output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with vim built-in `:sort`, you can do:

```
:sort! r /|*$/
```

If you want to sort by importance and alphabet, you can:

```
:sort|sort! r/|*$/
```

**Note** your **output** doesn't follow the rule you described.

Comment: +1 but to nitpick: the first sort isn't deterministic. If you apply it two times, the order changes *(incidently to what OP needs)*. The second sort is deterministic but the sort order is desc io asc as I believe OP requires *(I assume bar should be before cli as per Caek's comment)*.

Comment: Agreed. I made a mistake on that part. 
Thank you for the code snippets Kent. Second one does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the external linux `sort` command, you can run this inside vim:

```
:%!sort -k2r -k1,1
```

This sorts the second column in reverse order and if there are duplicates in the second column, then sort by the first column in ascending order.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Caek. I was looking for a solution in vim.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to do it in vim without messing around too much, so I learnt something from Kent's answer. +1 to him